# How to measure elapsed time in function on pandas.DataFrame column in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, timeit

I am trying to find out the elapsed time for the execution of a function to calculate information on a column of a `pd.DataFrame`

Here is an example of data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
import timeit 

df = pd.DataFrame(['year is 2009', 
                    '2010'
                    'edition 2008', 
                    '2010 found'],dtype="string", columns=['message'])
                    
def find_year(x):
    year = re.search('\d{4}', x)                    
    return int(year.group(0)) if year else np.nan
```

How do I measure how long it takes to do?

```py
df['year'] = df['message'].map(find_year)
```

On the real code the function is harder and I am trying to make it as efficient as possible. Therefore, I am looking to measure the execution time to optimize the function that is then applied.

I have tried:

```
print("The time taken is ",timeit.timeit(stmt="df['message'].apply(find_year)", number=100))
```

got the result with:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
start = timer()
df['phase_result'] = df['message'].apply(find_year)
end = timer()
print("The time taken is ", end - start)
```

This last method using default_timer does not allow me to include the argument `number=10000` that `timeit`uses.

Comment: where are you running the code?

Comment: i am using pycharm as an editor